# How to find specific table from DB in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

In my DB I have 642 tables.
I have to search specific table from it that name contain `EMPSAL` in it's name.
But like above so many tables are there which contain this KEYWORD in start of name or end of name or in between.

So I want to list tables that have `EMPSAL` in it's name at any place.

an I am newer to postgresql so I don't know that how to do so.

Is there any method that can help me to do so ?

Any suggestion for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query:

`SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='public'
AND table_type='BASE TABLE';`

Should give you a list of all the tables in your database. Then you can add something like this at the end:

`AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%EMPSAL%';`

Don't forget to remove the previous semicolon, or you're going to have a syntax error :)